# Proving one single solution for an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

let $f(y)$ be a continuous function in $R$.

$f(y)=0$ only for $y=y_0$.

as a result the integral:

$\int_y^{y_0} \frac1{f(x)}  dx  $

diverges for every $y$.

prove that the following problem:

$y'=f(y) , y(x_0)=y_0$

has only one single solution for every $x_0$.

My attempt:
according to Picard–Lindelöf theorem, in order to have one single solution we need f and $f'$ to be continuous in a rectangle around $(x_0,y_0)$. 
we are already given that $f$ is continuous around this point. I can't prove that the $f'$ is.

Comment: Care to tell us what have you tried? We're not a homework service you know.

Comment: Is divergency of $\int_y^{y_0}\frac{1}{f(t)}\,dt$ a hypothesis? $f(y_0)=0$ does not imply it.

Comment: it is given as part of this exam question.